# Can't access the data returned by api call to http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/3

Tags: reactjs, rest, fetch, postman

I`m trying to model an application for managing the employees of a company. My problem: I'm trying to fetch the data of a specific user, calling the API endpoint : http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/3 (the 3 can be replaced by other user-ids).
When I'm calling the endpoint from Postman I get this response [image]

But when I try to access the same resource from my React application I get this response.

[image]

Here is how I call the API endpoint

```
export async function getSingleEmployee() {
return fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/3', {
    mode: 'cors',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',

    }
})
    .then(response => response)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);

    })}
```

How can I access the data as I do in the Postman request? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "await" fetch.... ?

Comment: If you mean `export async function getSingleEmployee() {
    return await fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/3', {
        mode: 'cors',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
            'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',

        }
    })
        .then(response => response)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);

        })

}
` then yes, I`ve tried this. Same result

Comment: I tried the below and this just works fine for me. You can try this? And also I see an extra comma at the end of content-type inside header block. Not sure if thats ok...
async function getUserAsync() 
{
  let response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/<username>`);
  let data = await response.json()
  return data;
}

getUserAsync()
  .then(data => console.log(data));

Comment: I just tried from Postman and also on chrome. Postman gives me 200 but not the same response as yours instead I get an HTML content. Same response from chrome also hence the promise is rejected with error because it is not in JSON format. But it seems like you only need a dummy REST endpoint then you have options right ? Like the github or I tried with this https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2  and it works fine too.It has lot of sample REST endpoints in it or you can find more in Google.